# Shortcut key to "Save Note" in Google Notebook

Tags: google-workspace, keyboard-shortcuts

Whenever I do some edits in Google Notebook (the browser app) and I want to close the window (since I have finished editing) I will have to hit the "Save Now" button.

Is there any keyboard shortcut to do it?

Any "hacks" will be fine as long as I do not have to touch the mouse.

Comment: Are you talking about http://www.google.com/notebook or http://docs.google.com/ ?

Comment: @kzh yep the former

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build yourself a grease monkey script to handle a key binding or create an extension, but if I were you, I would not waste time on doing so since Google is about to close Google Notebook down. http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/fall-spring-clean.html